# Detecting of Real world Objects in video frame

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, occlusion

We are working on a project that involves interative Occlusion of real world and virtual objects.We need to detect real objects from the webcam caputre in realtime.
We are not able to find any relevant concept to be used to detect such real objects and make it behave as a physical object for virtual objects.

What we need is ability to predefine some parameters of an object that enables us to detect it in the video frame so that they can be assigned some physical attributes to interact with virtual ones.

Please suggest us some way that enables us to define a object and thus helping in its detection in the real time webcam capture.

Comment: I realise that OpenCV is very popular but please can we stop tagging *every* computer vision question with OpenCV ?

Comment: This would give a nice PhD thesis, wouldn't it?!

Answer (score 2):

Are you kidding me? Scientists has always wanted to do this....But still if you think you can then try using a 3D camera which can capture the dimensions and process it using a 3D software so they are turned into virtual 3D objects. Now they won't behave so real if the weight of those objects is unknown, so add some weight to them, then add some stiffness, hardness, etc. You can use software that will detect specific parts of the objects such as a unique feature that can be used to identify the object and its properties can be assigned to the virtual object.